# RESTful WCF Patch verb 401.3 error

Tags: iis, wcf-rest

I have REST web service on IIS 8.5. In Dev enviroment everything works OK, but on production environment I get "401 Unauthorised" error for PATCH requests. PUT and POST work without a problem. The service runs as an ApplicationPoolIdentity. It probably has something to do with ACL permissions, because if I give "everyone" permissions to folder where the service in installed it starts to work properly.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was to add full permissions to IUSR on the folder where service is installed. (Can someone explain why PUT and POST works without problem while PATCH not?)